# What are some good fonts to use for bullet characters?

Tags: print-design, font-recommendation, character

I'm designing a manual with the font [Akzidenz Grotesk](http://www.fonts.com/font/berthold/akzidenz-grotesk#product_top) as the main body font.

[image]

I am looking for some nice bullet characters but what are some fonts that provide good bullet characters?

Comment: A good bullet is an unobtrusive one. Most fonts will have a bullet designed to go with the font being used.

Comment: Yikes! I wait until I answer to see that someone changed the tag. Are we talking web or print here? I think that's a relevant question.

Comment: I was trying to restructure the question to fit better than simply a list of opinion based answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's staying on your PC, MS's Symbol and Wingdings fonts provide some good choices.

If you want something a little more modern with a nice set of icons and a really permissive license, why not use [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io)? There are some other icon sets out there - [Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/) and [Entypo](http://entypo.com/) come to mind, that were made for the screen but, depending on the icon and your use case, might work great for print.

The creator of Font Awesome will soon be producing an icon set called [Black Tie](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/232193852/font-awesome-black-tie), which will have different weights. That might be helpful.

I haven't used it personally I don't believe, but [Zapf Dingbats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zapf_Dingbats) has the pedigree. [FF Dingbats](http://ffdingbatsfont.com/) seems like a really solid choice as well.

Comment: You pretty much covered all the usual suspects. All of the pi fonts that ship with the OSes have a collection of useful bullet-type characters, including Wingdings and its siblings/offspring.